# Create a loop using SCSS to change background images with CSS3 animate?

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

I have created the beginning of a CSS3 animation as shown below. I have tried to use @for and @each within SCSS to create a loop which will increment the %'s and also the number of each background image. My knowledge of advanced SCSS like this is poor, so everything I have tried has been nonsense and trial and error based on reading the SCSS docs - and really not worth posting here.

Is it possible to use SCSS in this way to save having to type each keyframe?

```
.perimeterAnim {
    background-image: url('../img/perimeters/PerimeterFountains00.png');
    -webkit-animation: perimeter 5s infinite;
    -moz-animation: perimeter 5s infinite;
    -o-animation: perimeter 5s infinite;
    -ms-animation: perimeter 5s infinite;
    animation: perimeter 5s infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes perimeter {
    0% {
        background-image: url('../img/perimeters/PerimeterFountains00.png');
    }

    2.564102564102564% {
        background-image: url('../img/perimeters/PerimeterFountains01.png');
    }

    5.128205128205128% {
        background-image: url('../img/perimeters/PerimeterFountains02.png');
    }

    7.692307692307692% {
        background-image: url('../img/perimeters/PerimeterFountains03.png');
    }
```

**Edit:** The reason for creating the animation in this way is that the image is very large, so a sprite sheet is out of the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interpolation of prefixes on @keyframes in Sass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076063/interpolation-of-prefixes-on-keyframes-in-sass)

Comment: That question is regarding the prefixes of keyframes. My question is in regard to incrementing the % selectors and another variable for each numbered background image within an keyframes rule.

Comment: This is why you need to show what you've tried.  How do we know if you're having problems with the [percentage part](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488644/how-to-dynamically-generate-css3-keyframe-steps-using-sass) or the pairing of percentages to images ([looping through mappings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975811/function-to-dynamically-create-classes-from-lists) or lists of lists)?

Comment: I am sorry if my question was not clear enough. I am having problems with both of those parts. Your first link regarding the percentage part seems to address the issue on incrementing the %, but I can't comment on it to ask how I would increment the % in a way other than 1 by 1 as is shown in that answer. The second part is needing a variable that starts at 01 to be incremented in each loop, as you can see from the pattern in my example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sass can only increment (or decrement) `@for` loops by 1.  If you want a different interval, you need to use math to get there:

```
@-webkit-keyframes perimeter {
  @for $i from 0 through 39 {
    #{$i * 2.564102564102564%} {
      background-image: url('../img/perimeters/PerimeterFountains#{$i}.png');
    }
  }
}
```

Related:  [Rounding numbers in Sass and adjusting the amount of decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369643/rounding-in-sass)